# Find E{1/x} if we are given a density function with continuos random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

Let X be a continuous random variable with density function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{x}{30}(1+3x) & 1 < x < 3 \\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Find $E\left(\frac1x\right)$

Comment: The density function is, if I am reading correctly, $\frac{x}{30}(1+3x)$ at **some** values of $x$, and presumably $0$ elsewhere.  You have not specified **where** the density is $\frac{x}{30}(1+3x)$. If you do not, the problem cannot be solved.

Comment: i edited it, sorry, it was hidden for some reason

Answer (score 2):

$$E\left[\frac{1}{x}\right]=\int_1^3 \frac{1}{x}\cdot \frac{x}{30}(1+3x)\, dx$$

Now please simplify and do the integration if you want to learn something...

Comment: typo: not $0$ to $3$ but $1$ to $3$

Comment: @drhad: thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

If a random variable $X$ has density function $f(x)$, then the random variable $g(X)$ has mean 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)f(x)\,dx.$$
In your case, $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, so the mean of $\frac{1}{X}$  is
$$\int_1^3 \frac{1}{x}\frac{x}{30}(1+3x)\,dx.$$
The integration will be easy.